# dealing with a multidimensionnal array without pre-defined dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, dimension

```
trial=[];
trial=[trial 1];
```

works.

But not:

```
trial=[];
trial(1,:)=[trial(1,:) 1];
Attempted to access trial(1,:); index out of bounds because size(trial)=[0,0].
```

Can you please help me define the initial variable in this second case?

Thank you

Comment: It is better to preallocate a matrix, e.g. `trial=zeros(1, 100);`, even if you don't know the final size yet. You can count the number of trials (in say `n_tr`) and later shrink the variable to the appropriate size: `trial=trial(1:n_tr);`. The second example does not work even if `size(trial, 1)>0`, because it would attempt to assign more elements on the right to what can be assigned to on the left.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I don't want to preallocate the matrix with any value.

Comment: in any case, you can extend the variable just like in the first example – as long as all the dimensions match: `trial = []; trial = [trial, 1]; trial = [trial;42]; trial = [trial, [17; 7]]; trial = [trial; 1 2]; trial = cat(3, trial, [1,2;3,4;5,6]);` will all work.